# Что такое Eras в PersianCalendar?

Tags: c#

[PersianCalendar.GetMonth - метод (DateTime)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.getmonth(v=vs.110).aspx)

В примере неясно, откуда `jс.Eras` (это объект обращается к свойству(-вам)?) и почему оно вдруг равно 1?

```
foreach (int era in jc.Eras)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" era = {0}", era);
}
```

Comment: [Свойство PersianCalendar.Eras](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.eras(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [PersianCalendar.PersianEra - поле](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.persianera(v=vs.110).aspx) *Значение PersianEra равно 1.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если почитать чуть глубже :

[PersianCalendar.Eras](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.eras(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Значение свойства Type: System.Int32[] Массив целых чисел,
>   представляющий эры в объекте PersianCalendar.Этот массив состоит из
>   одного элемента, значение которого равно PersianEra.

.......

> Значение PersianEra равно 1.

Comment: спасибо - разобрался

Comment: @Proshka не забудьте отметить ответ как верный.